# Django filter by extra field on many to many relationship

Tags: python, django

I have this kind of model definition and I wish to have a list of product that have attribute distance < 40 from the respective product

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    near_duplicate_images = models.ManyToManyField("self", through="NearDuplicate")

class NearDuplicate(models.Model):
    first_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="first_product")
    second_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="second_product")
    distance = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I've tried doing this to directly access the relation

```py
p = Product.objects.filter(near_duplicate_images__distance__lt=40).prefetch_related('near_duplicate_images')
```

But it raise this exception

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Related Field got invalid lookup: distance
```

I've also tried doing this

```py
p = Product.objects.all().prefetch_related(Prefetch("near_duplicate_images", queryset=NearDuplicate.objects.filter(distance__lt=40), to_attr="near_duplicate_images_list"))
```

But it raise this exception

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'near_duplicate_images_rel_+' into field. Choices are: distance, first_product, first_product_id, id, second_product, second_product_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a query like this should work. As you want the list of products whose `distance` is less than 40.

```
products = NearDuplicate.objects.filter(distance__lt=40).values('first_product', 'second_product')
```

This would give an output similar to

```
<QuerySet [{'first_product': 1, 'second_product': 2}]>
```

**UPDATE** - I have played around the queries a bit. If you want to get the absolute list of products present in any of the `first_product` or `second_product`. You may need to use multiple queries like

```
q1= NearDuplicate.objects.filter(distance__lt=40).values_list('first_product', flat=True)
```

This would give output as

```
<QuerySet [1]>
```

and

```
q2 = NearDuplicate.objects.filter(distance__lt=40).values_list('second_product', flat=True)
```

This would give output as

```
<QuerySet [2]>
```

First query queries all the products listed in `first_product` and second query lists all the products present in `second_product`. Now you can merge them both and take out the distinct values using the following query

```
q1.union(q2).distinct()
```

This would give the final output as

```
<QuerySet [1, 2]>
```

I hope it helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need "near_duplicate_images" field.
Try something like (haven't tested):

```
p = Product.objects.filter(title__in=NearDuplicate.object.filter(first_product=current_product, distance=40).values('second_product',)
```

[QuerySet API - "_in"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#in)